# My inquisitiveness about my achievements

Tags: discussion

Does "English language and usage" reputations and badges subsume reputations and badges of "English language and usage meta" because they have the same user number?.I do not know whether my question is worth considering,But I wanted to work out my total achievements myself.

Comment: Each community has its own set of statistics. Click on your own username and select "Activity". Then click on the various menu items below the score chart to see your tags, badges and so on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No: although each site's Meta shows your points on that site*, badges are separate between Main and Meta.

Here are my Main and Meta scores as an example:

[image: Main site score]
[image: Meta site score]

The badges represent different achievements, and those achievements differ in each environment. It's not possible to get a [gold badge](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/badges/130/single-word-requests) in the [single-word-request](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-word-request) tag on Meta, for example, because that tag doesn't exist on Meta. Other badges, like *Reversal,* do exist on [Meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/50/reversal) and [Main](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/badges/50/reversal) — but they are still counted separately in each environment. At the time of this answer, no-one's yet been awarded a Main site *Reversal* badge in ELU.

[Meta.stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com) is a special case as that is really a "main" site in its own right and is not really related to stackexchange.com in the same way. My rep score on those two sites is very different.

*The score shown in Meta is updated less frequently than in the main-site environment and may lag behind.

Comment: Probably worth pointing out that it is not possible to have 'reputation on Meta'; upvotes here do not have any effect.

Comment: @TimLymington Meta has its own reputation, just hidden. See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/22307 .